# where can i add IF NOT EXISTS to this query to ensure I don't add any duplicate records?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to enter NAME, ID and EMAIL to a table based on the encodings fetched from video capture  and validated against existing encodings fetched from another table. Where should I add an IF NOT EXISTS clause or ON DUPLICATE control to this query to ensure I don't have any duplicate records?
Here's the insert query:

```
for encodeFace, faceloc in zip(encodesCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
        y1,x2,y2,x1 = faceloc
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 2)
        threshold=0.4
    

insert_script = "INSERT INTO meeting1(STUDENTID,STUDENTNAME,STUDENTEMAIL) SELECT STUDENTID,STUDENTNAME,STUDENTEMAIL FROM encodings WHERE sqrt(power(CUBE(array[{}]) <-> ENCODINGS, 2)) <= {} ".format(','.join(str(s) for s in encodeFace), threshold) + "ORDER BY sqrt(power(CUBE(array[{}]) <-> ENCODINGS, 2)) ASC LIMIT 1".format(','.join(str(s) for s in encodeFace))
```

I want to add another validation in that if there exists the same record with a different time than the current time then it could add the record. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

the solution is rather easy. Here's how I added it.

```
insert_script = "INSERT INTO meeting1(STUDENTID,STUDENTNAME,STUDENTEMAIL) SELECT STUDENTID,STUDENTNAME,STUDENTEMAIL FROM encodings WHERE sqrt(power(CUBE(array[{}]) <-> ENCODINGS, 2)) <= {}".format(','.join(str(s) for s in encodeFace), threshold) + "ORDER BY sqrt(power(CUBE(array[{}]) <-> ENCODINGS, 2)) ASC LIMIT 1".format(','.join(str(s) for s in encodeFace))+ "ON CONFLICT (STUDENTID) DO NOTHING"
```

i used the + to add a continuation of the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

These are some good links for your question:

https://codingsight.com/sql-insert-into-select-5-easy-ways-to-handle-duplicates/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm

Besides these, you can also do it using pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

df = df.drop_duplicates()

df.to_csv('filename_edited.csv')
```

Comment: thank you for you're response but I wasn't planning on including pandas to the system. the links though lead me to the answer.